# jQuery/JS Resize of iframe not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I try to resize an iframe with jQuery and JS. First I get the iframe out of a list of iframes and resize it when the iframe-content is ready.

> NOTE: The two-steps resize is necessary because otherwise after the
>   content of the iframe-page is a huge space.

**Problem:** In the while-loop I check if the content of the iframe is ready, when not I set a timeout of 1 second. But jQuery don’t check if the content ready it always goes inside the if and try to resize the iframe but fails because jQuery cannot get the size of a NULL element.

Has someone of you a solution for my problem?

**My Code:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var iframes = $(".my-iframe");
    $.each(iframes, function () {
        resizeIframe(this);
    });
});

function resizeIframe(iframe) {
    $(iframe).width("100%");
    var iframeIsReady = false;
    do
    {
        if ($(iframe).ready)
        {
            var iframeHeight = iframe.contentDocument.body.scrollHeight;
            $(iframe).height(iframeHeight);
            var iframeContentHeight = $(iframe).children("#DivInPage").height();
            $(iframe).height(iframeContentHeight);
            iframeIsReady = true;
        }
        else
        {
            setTimeout(resizeIframe(iframe), 1000);
        }
    }while(!iframeIsReady);
}
```

> **Edit:**
>
> Check out my solution

Comment: One issue I see is that in your setTimeout call you're trying to pass a call to resizeIframe but you're calling it instead, passing the result. You need `setTimeout( function() { resizeIframe(iframe); }, 1000);`

Comment: Is your iframe on the same domain as your page?

Comment: @Pekka웃 yes but there is no possibility to include the content of the iframe in my page without an iframe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution of my problem is:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var iframes = $(".my-iframe");
        $.each(iframes, function () {
            resizeIframe(this);
        });
    });

    function resizeIframe(iframe) {
        $(iframe).width("100%");
        setInterval(function () {
            //Check if the Content inside the iframe is ready
            if ($(iframe.contentDocument.body).ready) {
                var iframeHeight = iframe.contentDocument.body.scrollHeight;
                $(iframe).height(iframeHeight);
                var iframeContentHeight = $(iframe).children("#DivInPage").height();
                $(iframe).height(iframeContentHeight);
                //Close the Function
                return;
            }
        }, 1000);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi there is small change in your code please check following.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var iframes = $(".my-iframe")[0]; // $(".my-iframe"); /Edited
    $.each(iframes, function () {
        resizeIframe(this);
    });
});

function resizeIframe(iframe) {
    $(iframe).width("100%");
    var iframeIsReady = false;
    do
    {
        if ($(iframe.contentDocument).ready) // added 'iframe.contentDocument' instead of iframe
        {
            var iframeHeight = iframe.contentDocument.body.scrollHeight;
            $(iframe).height(iframeHeight);
            var iframeContentHeight = $(iframe).children("#DivInPage").height();
            $(iframe).height(iframeContentHeight);
            iframeIsReady = true;
        }
        else
        {
            setTimeout(resizeIframe(iframe), 1000);
        }
    }while(!iframeIsReady);
}
```

try this.

I checked code again found that $(".my-iframe") returns array of element object.
We need object here not array.
So i hard coded 0th index. you can use id instead of this.

Comment: sorry don't work. Error: jquery-3.0.0.js:3781 jQuery.Deferred exception: Cannot read property 'scrollHeight' of null TypeError: Cannot read property 'scrollHeight' of null

Comment: I only changed if condition.... iframe is replaced by iframe.contentDocument. 
and error you are telling is not regarding this. Please check

Comment: I checked it again and included the script and the iframe in another page and there is working fine because the page takes a longer time to refresh and on the time when the `resizeIframe()` function runs the content of the iframe is ready and I get no exception.